Disk appears as /dev/zram0, want to change to a /dev/sdX
I recently tried encrypting a hard drive on Windows using VeraCrypt.  It worked for a while but then it became corrupted by the look of it and could not be mounted.  All I want to do now is to be able to use the disk again (accepting that the data won't be accessible).
When I try to look at the disk from Ubuntu, it shows as /dev/zram0.  I have tried using fdisk to create a new partition on it but this has been unsuccessful.
How can I turn it into a /dev/sdX device that can then be mounted and written to?
Thanks for your help.

You have a Windows problem. Ubuntu can not show a disk as different then what it is. If you fix the Windows issue the disk should display as you want.

What happens when you try to use GParted partition editor in Ubuntu to reformat the hard drive?

Thanks for the replies.  I tried running GParted from the GParted live disk (latest version).    It gave me a Libparted warning: "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Remote I/O error Retry/Ignore".  Retry gives the same, Ignore gives a list of devices without sdb in it (and the devices listed do not contain my disk).

On Windows, I also get an I/O error when trying to access/modify the disk using the management options that come with Windows 11.  Thanks again.

It is from Seagate's IronWolf range.  It is only 3 months old.  I've running the tests from their SeaTools and it fails those quickly.  I don't think it's very well.

My next plan is to plug it into a SATA/usb cable and check that it still doesn't work (just in case the problem isn't the drive).  If that still doesn't work then I'll probably try contacting Seagate.  Thanks.

What do you see when you open "Disks" (gnome-disks) in Ubuntu? If you are seeing I/O errors, that sounds like it could be failing hardware, which you'd need to follow up with the manufacturer for a warranty claim / troubleshooting.
